# Obtaining array of attributes from an array of instances

Tags: python, arrays, class

I have a simple class `Foo` given by:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar: list):
        self.bar = bar
```

and an array of instances of this class `foos` given by:

```
foos = []
foos.append(Foo(bar=[1, 2]))
foos.append(Foo(bar=[3, 4]))
foos.append(Foo(bar=[5, 6]))
```

I want to get an array of `bars` such that:

```
bars = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

How do I go about this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
bars = [foo.bar for foo in foos]
```

Comment: Of course I can ... !